# Add class in sub menu

Tags: theming, navigation

I am trying to convert html to Drupal 7 theme.

`function theme_menu_tree($variables){
  return '<ul class="my-class-1">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}`

simply returns the entire menu how to make it like following
`<ul class="my-class-1">
  <li class="dropdown">Item
    <ul class="my-class-2">
      <li>Link1</li>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) function for it, see the below code

```
$title = 'Title';
$type = 'ol';
$items = array(
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'five',
);
$items[] = array(
  'data' => 'something',
  'class' => array('dummy'=>'category'),
  'children' => array('1.1','1.2',array('data'=>'1.3','class' => array('dummy'=>'category'),'children'=>array('1.3.1','1.3.2')))
);
$attributes = array('class' => array('test-class', 'demo-class'));

print theme_item_list(array(
  'items' => $items,
  'title' => $title,
  'type' => $type,
  'attributes' => $attributes
));
```

This will give you following HTML output:

```
<div class="item-list"><h3>Title</h3>
  <ol class="test-class demo-class">
    <li class="first">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li class="category last">something
      <div class="item-list">
        <ol class="category">
          <li class="first">1.1</li>
          <li>1.2</li>
          <li class="category last">1.3
            <div class="item-list">
              <ol class="category">
                <li class="first">1.3.1</li>
                <li class="last">1.3.2</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```